# Unable to upload file on s3 presigned url

Tags: php, amazon-s3, php-curl

I am trying to upload image on S3 Presigned url ,Presigned url is coming from thrird party API.If I tried with postman as binary body and choose file,it is working fine.But with curl it not working.I have tried following code.I am getting signature error.Please guide me.

```
$fields = array('file' => '@'.$_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name']);
$header = array('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$presigned_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result =curl_exec($ch);

$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} 
else{
 echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the aws-sdk instead, you can upload referring one file or stream data:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-a-file